# How to select a random row from subset of rows that are 20 percent from top(skip), limit 10 percent

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `questions`, and each question has a `difficulty` property,
I need a random question sorted by `difficulty` `ASC`, then skip 20 percent, limit 10 percent, and random of that subset.

Closest that I got:

```
select *, PERCENT_RANK() over ( order by difficulty ) from questions
```

Which would add another column to each row with percentage, then I can filter out required with `where` clause.

Then I realized that `PERCENT_RANK` is not working the way I want.
It calculates the percentage of the row compared to the sum of all difficulties of all rows. but I want a percentage of a `ROW_NUMBER` compared to the total number of rows.

So what I need is something like this:

```
select *, PERCENT_RANK() over ( 'ROW NUMBER SOMEHOW HERE' ) from questions order by difficulty
```

Comment: So do you want to remove all the questions with difficulty = 0 from your result set or want some another treatment for those questions?

Comment: I want to include them just like others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you combine the `row_number()` and `count()` analytic (window) functions, you can simply take the rows between 20% and 30%.

Something like this:

```
with cte as (
  select
    q.*, row_number() over (order by difficulty) as rn,
    count (*) over (partition by 1) as total
  from
    questions q
)
select *
from cte
where rn between total * 0.2 and total * 0.3
order by random()
```

The `order by random()` was just my response to your final comment of "and random of that subset."

Comment: Thanks a lot, just have a few follow-up questions, looks like `partition by 1` is redundant, I have removed it, and it works perfectly well.
By random of that subset I meant, a random single row.

Comment: You're right -- that was redundant.  I work with many DBMSs, and sometimes I forget which one needs which.  Postgres is definitely the most chill/flexible of them all.  On the random single row, I think if you add "limit 1" to the end it should do that.